# Implementing a drag-and-drop zone in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I recently started using Swift to build OS X apps and I am wondering how I could implement a drag-and-drop zone.

More specifically, I built an app that processes images but, for the moment, the user has to manually enter the path to the input images or use a File Chooser (which is quite annoying). I would like to improve my app allowing the user to input the images by a simple drag-and-drop (I only need to retrieve a String representing the path to the images).

How can I do this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's an example I'm using in an application.

1. Add conformance to `NSDraggingDestination` to your subclass declaration if necessary (not needed for `NSImageView` because it already conforms to the protocol)
2. Declare an array of accepted types (at least `NSFilenamesPboardType`)
3. Register these types with `registerForDraggedTypes`
4. Override `draggingEntered`, `draggingUpdated` and `performDragOperation`
5. Return an `NSDragOperation` from these methods
6. Get the file(s) path(s) from the `draggingPasteboard` array

In my example I've added a function to check if the file extension is amongst the ones we want.

**Swift 2**

```
class MyImageView: NSImageView {

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        // Declare and register an array of accepted types
        registerForDraggedTypes([NSFilenamesPboardType, NSURLPboardType, NSPasteboardTypeTIFF])
    }

    let fileTypes = ["jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png", "gif"]
    var fileTypeIsOk = false
    var droppedFilePath: String?

    override func draggingEntered(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        if checkExtension(sender) {
           fileTypeIsOk = true
           return .Copy
        } else {
           fileTypeIsOk = false
           return .None
        }
    }

    override func draggingUpdated(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        if fileTypeIsOk {
            return .Copy
        } else {
            return .None
        }
    }

    override func performDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        if let board = sender.draggingPasteboard().propertyListForType("NSFilenamesPboardType") as? NSArray,
            imagePath = board[0] as? String {
            // THIS IS WERE YOU GET THE PATH FOR THE DROPPED FILE
            droppedFilePath = imagePath
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    func checkExtension(drag: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        if let board = drag.draggingPasteboard().propertyListForType("NSFilenamesPboardType") as? NSArray,
            path = board[0] as? String {
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            if let fileExtension = url.pathExtension?.lowercaseString {
                return fileTypes.contains(fileExtension)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
class MyImageView: NSImageView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        // Declare and register an array of accepted types
        register(forDraggedTypes: [NSFilenamesPboardType, NSURLPboardType, NSPasteboardTypeTIFF])
    }

    let fileTypes = ["jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png", "gif"]
    var fileTypeIsOk = false
    var droppedFilePath: String?

    override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        if checkExtension(drag: sender) {
            fileTypeIsOk = true
            return .copy
        } else {
            fileTypeIsOk = false
            return []
        }
    }

    override func draggingUpdated(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        if fileTypeIsOk {
            return .copy
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }

    override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        if let board = sender.draggingPasteboard().propertyList(forType: "NSFilenamesPboardType") as? NSArray,
            imagePath = board[0] as? String {
            // THIS IS WERE YOU GET THE PATH FOR THE DROPPED FILE
            droppedFilePath = imagePath
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    func checkExtension(drag: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        if let board = drag.draggingPasteboard().propertyList(forType: "NSFilenamesPboardType") as? NSArray,
            path = board[0] as? String {
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            if let fileExtension = url.pathExtension?.lowercased() {
                return fileTypes.contains(fileExtension)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eric D. And Apple doc is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html

Comment: Warning: NSURLPboardType doesn't work anymore in Swift 4 and there's [no solution yet](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/79144). If you know how to use NSURLPboardType and these other constants in Swift 4 please make an edit or add your own answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4**

```
class MyImageView: NSImageView {

    let NSFilenamesPboardType = NSPasteboard.PasteboardType("NSFilenamesPboardType")

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        // Declare and register an array of accepted types
        registerForDraggedTypes([NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeFileURL as String),
                                 NSPasteboard.PasteboardType(kUTTypeItem as String)])
    }

    let fileTypes = ["jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png", "gif"]
    var fileTypeIsOk = false
    var droppedFilePath: String?

    override func draggingEntered(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        if checkExtension(drag: sender) {
            fileTypeIsOk = true
            return .copy
        } else {
            fileTypeIsOk = false
            return []
        }
    }

    override func draggingUpdated(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
        if fileTypeIsOk {
            return .copy
        } else {
            return []
        }
    }

    override func performDragOperation(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        if let board = sender.draggingPasteboard().propertyList(forType: NSFilenamesPboardType) as? NSArray,
            imagePath = board[0] as? String {
            // THIS IS WERE YOU GET THE PATH FOR THE DROPPED FILE
            droppedFilePath = imagePath
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    func checkExtension(drag: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
        if let board = drag.draggingPasteboard().propertyList(forType: NSFilenamesPboardType) as? NSArray,
            path = board[0] as? String {
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            if let fileExtension = url.pathExtension?.lowercased() {
                return fileTypes.contains(fileExtension)
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the Swift 4 version. Xcode asked me to add "let" before imagePath and path to have the code to work.

Answer (score 2):

This implementation allows for **multiple files**.

Just set the view class to `DragView` in Interface Builder, implement `DragViewDelegate` in your controller, then hook up the delegate outlet in Interface Builder. This way you get a delegate callback with the file URLs.

```swift
func dragViewDidReceive(fileURLs: [URL])
{
    // Yay!
}
```

**`DragView.swift`**

```swift
//
//  DragView.swift
//
//  Copyright (c) 2020 Geri Borbás http://www.twitter.com/_eppz
//
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

import Cocoa


@objc protocol DragViewDelegate
{


    func dragViewDidReceive(fileURLs: [URL])
}


class DragView: NSView
{


    @IBOutlet weak var delegate: DragViewDelegate?
    let fileExtensions = ["pdf"]


    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        color(to: .clear)
        registerForDraggedTypes([.fileURL])
    }

    override func draggingEntered(_ draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation
    {
        var containsMatchingFiles = false
        draggingInfo.draggingPasteboard.readObjects(forClasses: [NSURL.self], options: nil)?.forEach
        {
            eachObject in
            if let eachURL = eachObject as? URL
            {
                containsMatchingFiles = containsMatchingFiles || fileExtensions.contains(eachURL.pathExtension.lowercased())
                if containsMatchingFiles { print(eachURL.path) }
            }
        }

        switch (containsMatchingFiles)
        {
            case true:
                color(to: .secondaryLabelColor)
                return .copy
            case false:
                color(to: .disabledControlTextColor)
                return .init()
        }
    }

    override func performDragOperation(_ draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool
    {
        // Collect URLs.
        var matchingFileURLs: [URL] = []
        draggingInfo.draggingPasteboard.readObjects(forClasses: [NSURL.self], options: nil)?.forEach
        {
            eachObject in
            if
                let eachURL = eachObject as? URL,
                fileExtensions.contains(eachURL.pathExtension.lowercased())
            { matchingFileURLs.append(eachURL) }
        }

        // Only if any,
        guard matchingFileURLs.count > 0
        else { return false }

        // Pass to delegate.
        delegate?.dragViewDidReceive(fileURLs: matchingFileURLs)
        return true
    }

    override func draggingExited(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo?)
    { color(to: .clear) }

    override func draggingEnded(_ sender: NSDraggingInfo)
    { color(to: .clear) }

}


extension DragView
{


    func color(to color: NSColor)
    {
        self.wantsLayer = true
        self.layer?.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Swift is this in? Rookie here, can't tell just by looking. :)

Comment: @JoshuaDance by looking at the date, this was probably Swift 5.1 targeting macOS 10.15. Why you ask?

Comment: learning Swift and the version matters more than I was aware. Some examples of code won't work etc.