# AlamofireImage: Is it possible to get the raw data from an NSimageview in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am using an imagewell to accept jpg images being pasted or dragged into my OSX app.  The problme is that I am struggling to get the original jpg images as OSX seems to requires me to get the Tiff version of the NSImage if I want to uplod via Alamo Fire.

Does AlamoFireImage have a fancy way of getting the original url / original raw data without converting to Tiff first?

Comment: I can't seem to get it from the well. Is there a method to get it?

Comment: add that as a solution.. looks better way to achieve it

Comment: I've made an answer. Thanks! It is a better way for your needs, yes, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, with an `NSImageWell`, you don't have much possibilities regarding the dropped image. It's a convenient class for *showing* dropped images but as soon as you need to do more, it's not up to the task.

I suggest you use an `NSImageView` instead, and *add drag and drop capabilities* to it like in my example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29233824/2227743

This way you can easily get the dropped image's URL (and filename), and the image data itself of course.